# Is there a way to say if x is true print y from the same row

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
    Time              degF
    10/2/2019 8:20        78.8
    10/2/2019 8:21        79
    10/2/2019 8:21        79
    10/2/2019 8:21        79
    10/2/2019 8:21        79
    10/2/2019 8:21        79
    10/2/2019 8:21        79
    10/2/2019 8:22        79.5
    10/2/2019 8:22        81.9
    10/2/2019 8:22        88.3
    10/2/2019 8:22        99.5
```

Is there a way to program 'if degF = 79.5, print the Time associated with that row.' So in this case it would spit out 10/2/2019 8:22.

So far I have an if statement that states when degF hits the value in question, to print out the time. But right now its printing all of the values of time rather than the one that corresponds to the same row since I'm not sure how to code that.

```
    for i in degF:
        if i == 79.5:
           print(Time)
```

Comment: If there's multiple times that share that temperature, should it print all the times associated? Say it was 79 deg, should it print the 6 times with temperature of 79? Or is guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Also, what are you representing your table as in python? Is it a dictionary, a list, or something else?

Comment: If time is also a list, use zip: `for i,t in zip (degf, times): if i==79: print (t)`

Comment: Im new to python so I hope this will answer the question. Right now I imported a csv file from computer and then used to_datetime and to_numeric to make the values from strings. So im not sure if this qualifies as a list, dict, or other. And yes, it should print out all times associated.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start from the import cause this is key. Assuming data is stored "date_information, temp" and each new set of information is on a new line then:

```
import csv
dataList = []

with open("csvFileName.csv", "r") as file:
    line_data = csv.reader(file)

    for line in line_data:
        dataList.append([line[0], line[1]])

userRequest = input("What temp do you want the time information for?")

for valuePairs in dataList:
    if userRequest == valuePairs[1]:
        print("Time associated with temp {}: {}".format(userRequest, valuePairs[0]))
    else:
        print("No time data for that temp.")
```

Basically what is happening is you load your csv data into a list holding both time and temp. We append that to a storage list. Then we do a basic search in that list for the temp you want and return a time if that temp is in the csv.